# How to save an Entity without the object Id or an id MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Um looking for a way to save a collection without an Id
My Entity Declaration as follows

```
                public class TestA : IEntity
                    {
                        public string AppleSet { get; set; }
                        public string MapSted { get; set; }

                        [BsonIgnore]
                        public string Id { get; set; }


                    }
```

I need to declare ID field in the entity, is there a way to tell mongodb to ignore Id for a specific entity and save it to the database?

Comment: Every object must have an `_id` if that's what you meant. It's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A document *must* have an id. That is a requirement of the database itself. Even if you convince the driver to attempt to insert a document without an id, mongod itself will [add an `_id` field automatically](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/#id-field). As you can see from this link, the inserted `_id` will be returned and is hence part of the lower-level API. As such, `_id` is not just any other field, but has special semantics, one rule being that it has to be unique.